# Search by column in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search, redux

Someone would know how can I make a search by column in ReactJS ? 
I didn't find anything on the web so I'm here to ask for help.
I have a `Table` with `TextInput` inside like this and I use Redux.[image]

The problem is that the search works fine, but on all fields at the same time, like this:
[image]

**Here is the search function:**

```
useEffect(() => {
    setData(
      searchText.length === 0
        ? fournisseurs
        : _.filter(fournisseurs, fournisseur => {
            return (
              fournisseur.raisonSociale
                .toLowerCase()
                .includes(searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
              fournisseur.telephone
                .toLowerCase()
                .includes(searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
              fournisseur.codePostal
                .toLowerCase()
                .includes(searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
              fournisseur.ville
                .toLowerCase()
                .includes(searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
              fournisseur.categorie
                .toLowerCase()
                .includes(searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
              fournisseur.codeFournisseur
                .toLowerCase()
                .includes(searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
              fournisseur.mail.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
            );
          })
    );
  }, [fournisseurs, searchText]);
```

**The Redux action:**

```
export function setFournisseursSearchText(event)
{
    return {
        type      : SET_FOURNISSEURS_SEARCH_TEXT,
        searchText: event.target.value
    }
}
```

**The reducer (with initial state):**

```
import * as Actions from '../actions';

const initialState = {
    data      : [],
    searchText: ''
};

const fournisseursReducer = function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch ( action.type )
    {
        case Actions.GET_FOURNISSEURS:
        {
            return {
                ...state,
                data: action.payload
            };
        }
        case Actions.SET_FOURNISSEURS_SEARCH_TEXT:
        {
            return {
                ...state,
                searchText: action.searchText
            };
        }
        default:
        {
            return state;
        }
    }
};

export default fournisseursReducer;
```

**And the `textInput` which call `setFournisseursSearchText` action from redux:**

```
<TextareaAutosize
 onChange={ev =>
   dispatch(Actions.setFournisseursSearchText(ev))
 }
 value={searchText}
 aria-label="rechercher"
 placeholder="Rechercher"
 className={classes.textField}
/>
```

I'm confused, it's probably easy but I'm not sure how to do it. I hope I've made it clear and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Simply because you've got `value={searchText}` on all of your inputs, what you should be doing is giving each input a `name` or an `id`, and only dispatch the changed value for that particular named field.

Should look sth like this:

```
export function setFournisseursSearchText({ target: { name, value } })
{
    return {
        type      : SET_FOURNISSEURS_SEARCH_TEXT,
        [name]: value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just using same function for all input's onChange. And it's brillience practice. But problem here is you also use one value for all inputs. So, What you can do is:

1) Set unique name attribute to all inputs.
example:

```
<TextareaAutosize
 onChange={ev =>
   dispatch(Actions.setFournisseursSearchText(ev))
 }
 value={searchText["rechercher"]}
 name="rechercher"
 aria-label="rechercher"
 placeholder="Rechercher"
 className={classes.textField}
/>
```

Once you done for all inputs. just change little bit for reducer and action as follows:

The Redux action:

```
export function setFournisseursSearchText({ target: {value, name}})
{
    return {
        type      : SET_FOURNISSEURS_SEARCH_TEXT,
        searchText: {
               [name] : value
        }
    }
}
```

The reducer (with initial state):

```
import * as Actions from '../actions';

const initialState = {
    data      : [],
    searchText: ''
};

const fournisseursReducer = function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch ( action.type )
    {
        case Actions.GET_FOURNISSEURS:
        {
            return {
                ...state,
                data: action.payload
            };
        }
        case Actions.SET_FOURNISSEURS_SEARCH_TEXT:
        {
            return {
                ...state,
                searchText: {
                  ...state.searchText,
                  ...action.searchText
                }
            };
        }
        default:
        {
            return state;
        }
    }
};

export default fournisseursReducer;
```

I hope this will help you.